# How to extract ngrams features for sarcasm detection in R for a large dataset?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am doing a project on sarcasm detection using R. The data is a balanced dataset that has 1 million rows having 0.5 million sarcastic and 0.5 million non-sarcastic comments. Need help in ngram feature extraction using R.

I am following the code given below to extract bigram features. But the problem is the size of data and I guess the code is also not efficient enough to process such huge data. I tried by taking first 50K data. The features are getting generated but if I give a large data it is consuming a lot of time to run and moreover, R is also throwing an error, vector of size 3.5 GB can not be allocated.
I was exploring ngram package provided by R but couldn't find an example related to it. Would be great if anyone could help me on this.

Creating list:-

```
ngram_list <- sarcasticTweets[c(0:50000),] %>% 
unnest_tokens(bigram,'comment', token="ngrams", n=2)%>%
separate(bigram, c("word1", "word2"), sep = " ") %>%
filter(
!word1 %in% stop_words$word,                 
!word2 %in% stop_words$word,
!str_detect(word1, pattern = "[[:digit:]]"), 
!str_detect(word2, pattern = "[[:digit:]]"),
!str_detect(word1, pattern = "[[:punct:]]"), 
!str_detect(word2, pattern = "[[:punct:]]"),
!str_detect(word1, pattern = "(.)\\1{2,}"),  
!str_detect(word2, pattern = "(.)\\1{2,}"),
!str_detect(word1, pattern = "\\b(.)\\b"),   
!str_detect(word1, pattern = "\\b(.)\\b")
)%>%
unite("bigram", c(word1, word2), sep = " ") %>%
count(bigram) %>%
filter(n >= 3) %>% # filter for bi-grams used 10 or more times
pull(bigram)
```

Feature extraction:-

```
ngram_features <- sarcasticTweets[c(0:50000),] %>%
unnest_tokens(bigram, `comment`, token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>%
filter(bigram %in% ngram_list) %>%    
count(ID, bigram) %>%                 
spread(bigram, n) %>%                
map_df(replace_na, 0)
```

Comment: Where can we view this data resource? You might also help out your audience, most of whom I predict have no idea that "lahk" is a number.

Comment: And you might mention what "X" is in that memory error message.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have changed my question accordingly. The data is downloaded from Kaggle:- https://www.kaggle.com/kashnitsky/a4-demo-sarcasm-detection-with-logit-solution/data

Comment: You might want to look at quanteda as that does everything in c++ and works in parallel. Though the tokenizers package that tidytext calls for tokenizing works in c++, you will avoid some overhead and gain more speed. But if the data is too large for your machine, you will either need to do everything in chunks and combine later, or move to a AWS or Azure solution.